# Complex SQL where clause with great than and less than

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-query-store

```
@fromValue FLOAT; @toValue FLOAT;
SELECT *
 FROM INVOICE
 WHERE TOTAL > @fromValue and TOTAL < @toValue
```

I have a INVOICE table with TOTAL column. I want to select in 3 conditions in a combobox like this:

- TOTAL < 100 --> (@fromValue = 0 ; @toValue = 100)
- 100 < TOTAL < 200 --> (@fromValue = 100 ; @toValue = 200)
- TOTAL > 500 --> (@fromValue =500; @toValue ???)

Comment: _What_ do you want to conditionally select based on those 3 ranges? (Not my downvote)

Comment: I want to write just one query sentence

Comment: I don't understand it at all, Sample data and expected results will be the best explanation.

Comment: Sorry! I have just editted my question

Comment: So are you just asking for three separate queries?  The deleted answer by @lad2025 looks spot on actually.

Comment: No, Just one query for 3 conditions, when I select each condition : I willl set value for parameters : fromValue and toValue

Comment: @data Same conditions for one query at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass variables like:

```
DECLARE @fromValue DECIMAL(18,4), @toValue DECIMAL(18,4);

SET @fromValue = 500 ; -- depending on initial value
--SET @toValue = NULL;

SELECT *
FROM INVOICE
WHERE TOTAL BETWEEN ISNULL(@fromVALUE,0) AND ISNULL(@toValue,9999999);
```

Comment: I don't want use maxValue like 9999999

Comment: @data  `TOTAL > 500` could be equivalent to `(500, somer_really_big_numbe)`

Comment: Thanks! Can you use IF or CASE WHEN instead of your above Where Clause ?

Comment: @data His query is saying if _no_ max value is specified then don't place any upper limit on the total.

Comment: Thank @TimBiegeleisen, Should I use above or query with where clause:     WHERE ( TOTAL > fromValue ) AND (TOTAL < (SELECT TOP 1 TOTAL FROM INVOICE ORDER BY TOTAL DECS))

Answer (score 0):

I must be missing something, because it seems too straightforward?

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    Invoice
WHERE
    Total < 100 OR Total Between 100 and 200 OR Total > 500
```

Comment: That's simply `SELECT` any value, I don't understand those conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine or understand what you need exactly, but if you want to pass two(2) values and use it then:

```
SELECT *
FROM INVOICE
WHERE TOTAL BETWEEN @fromValue AND @toValue;
```